# Regrowth - Legit way to progress in the dream world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I am currently playing the modpack Regrowth, where you have several things to accomplish. I came to the dream world (where you lose all your inventory when entering) and am trying to get the necessary stuff to progress.

I know there is various ways to cheat to bring directly any item with you in the dream world, but I don't want to cheat. Anyway, I can't figure what is supposed to be the legit way to get a pickaxe able to mine diamond. Presently I have a flint pickaxe, enough to mine copper but nothing harder, and a smeltery (from the grout the spawns underground) but no metal to make the casts.

There is still the option to make tin seeds and get tin essence, the same way I did in the overworld, but honestly I don't want to re-do all that. Moreover the difficulty to get enderpearls (necessary to get the infusion stone needed to get the seeds) and the presence of ores seems to indicate I don't need these seeds.

Am I missing something obvious here ?

Comment: What about TNT? If you go during the nightmare time, I know creepers spawn. But oh the otherhand I know regrowth stopped TNT from being useful for mining high tier ores from the nether, so maybe not.

Answer (score 1):

**You are not missing anything obvious**.

The Spirit World, aka Dreamworld, in Witchery simply mirrors the generation of the Overworld. The Spirit World exists primarily to get materials that only generate there, and items that can only be crafted there, i.e. Wispy Cotton, Disturbed Cotton, Brews of Flowing Spirit, etc. Because of Witchery's nature emphasis, crafting most of these items are not that difficult, some iron is required to build a kettle. The Spirit World does not seem to have been designed to play permanently in. As you pointed out: it is difficult to get enderpearls. This is because "Endermen cannot enter the Spirit World."

TL;DR The Spirit World is designed as a challenging way to get top tier ingredients in the Witchery mod. It is not meant to be the primary world of play.

**Sources:**

Playing with the Witchery Mod previously

https://sites.google.com/site/witcherymod/spirit-world

Comment: How do you get iron and diamond for the kettle? My problem here is that the pickaxes tiers are differents from vanilla and i can't just make a copper pick without a cast.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Since I don't have much experience with the Regrowth mod pack, I just looked at it briefly however, it seems to me like you may need to repeat whatever steps you used in the Overworld to obtain the items you need. I know I always had to repeat my steps whenever I first entered the Spirit World. However, I will say this: Regrowth looks to me like a pack designed to make it hard to progress, so whatever steps you used in the Overworld may be the easiest way. Sadly this is not a limitation by Witchery, but rather, by the mod pack creators. Hope this helps.

Comment: Until this very point there was only one other quest that took me insanely long: making the apiarist stuff. Repeating what I did in the Overworld won't work because of the need for enderpearls, which I plan to pass through by using oysters. It will be a long, long road...

Answer (score 0):

Um, it's not that simple.. a kettle requires an *attuned stone* aka you need to get into botany and all that, you need an alfheim portal just to throw a mana diamond into for dragonstone to make attuned stone .-. All of that just to make a kettle... So it takes a lot of work, if I were you just use the tinker's belt, it's not the biggest deal in the world if you use it to take a kettle with you :P

Unless you really want to spend another 3 days gathering materials to make the crucible to get the smeltery to get the casts you need to make a decent pickaxe to mine for the materials you need, and then as well as try to start over in botany trying to get all you need to make mana spreaders, some kind of flower to power em, mana pool, alfheim portal, terrasteel ingots/nuggets, the crystals to make the portal... way too much work. Imo I think they intended some way for you to do it faster but didn't add it in by accident? Because that's just too much work. Especially since you can't even get the quest rewards to accelerate you forward, just for a damn bucket of flowing spirit.